# Convert date stored as VARCHAR in MYSQL to MYSQL Compatible Date

Tags: php, mysql, str-to-date

I have a database that I receive every month that I simply import through CSV into MYSQL. I don't worry about preserving any old database entries, so I just overwrite the old database with the new entries monthly.

I want to be able to sort through the database by month, however I currently need to import the date field as VARCHAR, or risk having to manually convert tons of entries to fit the formatting of the MYSQL date field.

I would like to take the entries stored in the 'Expiration Date' field and be able to run a query that will convert them to a MYSQL date format and then write them to a new column named 'Expiration_Converted' so that I can then run date functions to show me all dates from a month, year, etc.

I know about the STR_TO_DATE function in MYSQL, however I'm not quite sure how to pull this off. I'm writing everything in PHP.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try editing the question and showing samples of the dates that need to be converted.

Comment: I don't know that the duplicate noted above is actually a duplicate for this question.  I suppose it is if you want a PHP solution, but likely there is a simple UPDATE query to be run here to solve this problem.  OP should try opening a new question with specific examples of the data format(s) you are trying to change, as well as queries that have been tried that are not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

I'm still using this script in my web application when I get the value from a text field and need to converto to MySQL DATE Format:

```
$format = '/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/';
    if ($_date != null && preg_match($format, $_date, $parts)) {
        $date = date_create($parts[3].'-'.$parts[2].'-'.$parts[1]);
        $final_formated = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
        return $final_formated;
    }
```

PS: $_date variable receives a date string.

After running this script, I can store date in Database.

Hope it helps you.